# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word creating unwanted folder with XML and theme files. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I'm creating a Winforms app, and using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to open a document and get the number of pages.  It usually works fine.  On certain files, as it is doing this, it creates a new folder ("name of document"_files), and in that folder creates three new files (colorschememapping.xml, filelist.xml, and themedata.thmx).  The document in question is a Word 97-2003 Doc with extension .doc.  It doesn't do this for other files of the same type.  Only with certain ones.  It still correctly returns the number of pages.  This is the code I am using:

```
public int PageCountWord(object Path)
    {
        // Get application object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // Get document object
        object Miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object ReadOnly = false;
        object Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = WordApplication.Documents.Open(ref Path, ref Miss, ref ReadOnly, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Visible, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss);

        // Get pages count
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic PagesCountStat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
        int PagesCount = Doc.ComputeStatistics(PagesCountStat, ref Miss);
        Doc.Close();
        WordApplication.Quit();
        return PagesCount;
    }
```

And it creates the folder and files during the Doc.Close() line.

Anyone know why this would happen, and if I can prevent it? (other than researching the folder when I'm done and deleting anything newly created)

Also, unfortunately, the documents contain sensitive information, so I cannot upload one.  Hopefully someone has had this same issue, and discovered a solutions

Comment: I would like to add that the Application.Quit() method accepts three optional paramaters (two enums and a boolean), and that no combination of these prevents this behavior.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/application-quit-method-word

Comment: Have you tried passing `SaveChanges: false` to the document close method?

Comment: Yes I tried that.  That is one of the optional parameters.

Comment: I asked because in your sample code you're just calling `Doc.Close()` without any parameters. The documentation doesn't state what the default for `SaveChanges` is: I was wondering if in this particular document the act of opening it caused a change, which was then being saved, as you say _" it creates the folder and files during the Doc.Close() line"_. Your original comment about "three optional parameters" references `Application.Quit()`, did you mean `Doc.Close()` there?

Comment: Yes!  Sorry, I forgot which line was causing my problem.  It's been a long day.  But anyway, if you pass in wdDoNotSaveChanges to Doc.close(), it works fine and does not create these extra files.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
    public int PageCountWord(object Path)
    {
        // Get application object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // Get document object
        object Miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object ReadOnly = false;
        object Visible = false;
        object SaveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = WordApplication.Documents.Open(ref Path, ref Miss, ref ReadOnly, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Visible, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss, ref Miss);

        // Get pages count
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic PagesCountStat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
        int PagesCount = Doc.ComputeStatistics(PagesCountStat, ref Miss);
        Doc.Close(SaveChanges);
        WordApplication.Quit();
        return PagesCount;
    }
```

Comment: I just realized I am using that options parameter, however, in my case, going from doc to html, it creates a folder full of xmls. Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: Also, it is not in the Close method but in the SaveAs Method, and none of the attributes described here seems to help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Solved it. and may be it can help others. on the save as document Iwas using Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML. I changed to Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML and the folder is no longer created and the output file is cleaner too.